# How do I change the D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAGS in swapchian?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I want to copy the backbuffer in DX12 to different devices. I knew I can create a 2D resource with shared flags and copy backbuffer to the resource. So I can share the resource with different devices.

```
D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC bkDesc = p_BkDes;

bkDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET | D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_SIMULTANEOUS_ACCESS;
```

Is there any other way else?

Answer (score 0):

where are you planning to use this D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC bkDesc.

the other way is you can use shared resource api to share your Backbuffer to other devices. just share it with certain handle and open that NT handle in other device.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/shared-heaps
```